# Huge memory leak in javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas, memory, memory-leaks

I'm working on a canvas element, and I thought I'd add some simple graphics elements, but for some reason they are grinding the fps to a halt. Without them it's 60fps, with them it slows down to 3-4 fps within a minute of it running:

```
ctx.rect(0, 0, cnv.width, cnv.height);
ctx.fillStyle = ctx.createPattern(albImg[8], "repeat");
ctx.fill();

ctx.lineWidth="1";
ctx.strokeStyle="#5d92de";
ctx.rect(173.5,638.5,623,98);
ctx.stroke();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what are the image properties of albImg[8]? is it huge?

Comment: Why are you creating a new pattern every frame? That can't be fast.

Comment: yeah, you're right, I should probably do the pattern in a seperate context instead and then use that

Ssube: No, it's a tiny icon - 358 bytes.

The weird part is that even if I comment out those top 3 lines, it still grinds to a halt with just those remaining 4 lines - it just takes a little bit longer, which is really weird.

with all 7 lines removed the rest of the canvas runs just fine for hours without a dip in fps.

Comment: OK, so I found the problem with the last lines: I was using ctx.stroke rahter than strokeRect.

The first part with the background remains a mystery to me though, it still doesn't work properly even if I define it outside of the loop.

 [code]var muhpatturn = ctx.createPattern(albImg[8], "repeat");

 function mechbay(){
 ctx.rect(0, 0, cnv.width, cnv.height);
 ctx.fillStyle = muhpatturn;
 ctx.fill();

 ctx.lineWidth=1;
 ctx.strokeStyle='#5d92de';
 ctx.strokeRect(173.5,638.5,623,98);
[/code]

Comment: @DanielBengtsson, Yes, as you've discovered, use strokeRect. Alternatively, you can add `ctx.beginPath` before `ctx.rect`. What's happening is that all previous rects are being redrawn since the last `beginPath` so you are really drawing hundreds of rects as you animate.

Comment: thanks, Mark I didn't know that that was what stroke did - I'll be sure to remember that.

Any idea how I can resolve the background issue?

Comment: @DanielBengtsson. Background: Your code is ok (but again...use fillRect or begin your pattern rect with `beginPath`), so I suspect your pattern image has not fully loaded by the time you try to use that pattern image. I've added an answer showing how to wait for the pattern image to load before using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Animation slows with each new animation loop**

@DanielBengtsson, Yes, as you've discovered, use strokeRect.

Alternatively, you can add ctx.beginPath before ctx.rect. What's happening is that all previous rects are being redrawn since the last beginPath so you are really drawing hundreds of rects as you animate.

```
// alternative with beginPath so previous rects will not redraw and
//     cause slowdowns.
ctx.lineWidth="1";
ctx.strokeStyle="#5d92de";
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.rect(173.5,638.5,623,98);
ctx.stroke();
```

**Repeating Background Pattern -- wait for the image to fully load before trying to use it**

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw = canvas.width;
var ch = canvas.height;

var img = new Image();
img.onload = start;
img.src = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/emoticon1.png";

function start() {
  ctx.fillStyle = ctx.createPattern(img, "repeat");
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}
```

```css
#canvas{border:1px solid red; margin:0 auto; }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```